# Ram on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I run windows XP both 32 bit and 64 bit versions on virtual machines, I understand the 64 bit OS does ocupy a little more RAM than the 32, but is it a big difference? I don´t do may things on windows so I don´t need too much RAM designated to my virtual machines, and I wouldn´t like to spend a lot of RAM on them, but should I use 32 bit rather than 64 bit and assign a little less RAM? or is not not much difference using the 64 bit? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It does technically use more RAM than the 32bit version, but it's much extra (especially when you are using 4GB+). If you are not assigning more than 4GB of RAM to the virtual machine and don't have any 64bit programs to run on it, I wouldn't consider it worth the trouble. The 64bit version of XP was never properly supported by Microsoft and it has compatibility issues with several programs.

Answer (score 0):

Im an extreme novice on the subject but if it were me and because I know that 64 bit systems are ALLOWED to (not demanded to) use greater than a set amount of ram (4gb? or maybe 8gb?) I would stick with just 64-bit, more functionality, more uses. Downfall is that some programs require 32-bit systems and thus dont go throwing out that 32-bit xp because you have a 64-bit.

Comment: 64-bit Windows can run 32-bit Windows programs through WOW64.

Answer (score 0):

Like they say, if it aint broke, dont fix it.  Unless you are running out of RAM on your host machine, then there is no need to change a thing.